# Change Unlock method after device restart via ADB

Tags: lock-screens, password, pattern-lock

My Android 11 device is asking for a password after I reboot in addition to the fingerprint auth. I forgot the password. Is there a way to change the default unlock screen to pattern unlock?

Note developer mode is enabled and I can access the device via adb, however, the device is not rooted.

Erasing the device will be the last resort.

Comment: The password is necessary to enable decryption of your user data by the Android integrated gatekeeper system. You can not change the lock screen password or type without performing a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

Even erasing the device 'might not' help since these days OEMs store your device password in specific partitions which doesnt wipe when you 'reset' from recovery mode. So if your device asks you the password even after factory reset and you see no options to reset it e.g., using Google Account, the last resort will be flashing stock ROM overwriting every partition except the ones that store IMEI. I'm sorry cant help with a specific guide since (1) You didnt mention your phone OEM and model (2) I might not be able to write one even you did (thanks to OEM defragmentation)

Comment: I think you are mixing up the device password with the Google password. The latter is the one that is saved for the Factory Reset Protection (FRP). FRP requires you to enter the Google password after a factory reset of a locked device.

Comment: Nope im not mixing it. These days, our "lockscreen password" is also stored in some other partition on your device which doesnt wipe off even after a factory reset.